# vuejs axios download get filename

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, axios

I'm downloading a file from an asp net API, but I can't get the filename with the extension sent from the server, in the browser I can see the header

```
"content-disposition: attachment; filename=AEDAF367-D922-470E -9D0F-09F84BDCA0AC.zip; filename*=UTF-8''AEDAF367-D922-470E-9D0F-09F84BDCA0AC.zip"
```

but in axios the "content-disposition" header does not arrive in the headers

```
headers:
content-length: "1270333"
content-type: "application/zip"
last-modified: "Wed, 27 Apr 2022 14:59:41 GMT"
```

my code ASP CORE

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName("C:\file.zip");
Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
return PhysicalFile(reg.dirpc, MimeTypes.GetMimeType("C:\file.zip"), fileName);
```

my VueJS code

```
            await api.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).then((response) => {
                const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.data.type });
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                console.log('response = ', response);
                const contentDisposition = response.headers['content-disposition'];
                console.log('contentDisposition = ', contentDisposition);
                let fileName = 'unknown';
                if (contentDisposition) {
                    const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/);
                    if (fileNameMatch.length === 2)
                        fileName = fileNameMatch[1];
                }
                link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                link.remove();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('ERRO POST: ', error);
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log('error data=', error.response.data);
                    }
                }
            });
```

thanks!

Comment: Hi @MarilNova, I test the code and it gives the correct header. Does your header get nothing? Where does the vue.js code run?

Comment: the problem was on the server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently get this same problem.

to solve this from the server side you need to set this response header:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "*"`

for more secure option:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ["Content-Disposition","Content-Type","My-Custom-Header"]`

you can add your own header you like too,

this will allow AXIOS to read those headers,
[image]

reference: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1946#issuecomment-958790245

good luck!